# Where should I ask a question regarding the usage of GIMP?

Tags: discussion, tags, site-recommendation

[I've just asked a question](https://superuser.com/questions/1650353/ive-accidentally-hidden-the-menubar-in-gimp-how-do-i-get-it-back) about GIMP on SuperUser, but while forming the question and doing additional research I checked out the GIMP tag and saw that it has the following description:

> GIMP is the GNU Image Manipulation Program. It is a freely distributed piece of software for such tasks as photo retouching, image composition and image authoring. It works on many operating systems, in many languages. **Scripting questions on Stack Overflow, installing questions on Super User, how to use the program on Graphic Design.**

Since my question was about the operation of the program, I then went to Graphic Design and checked out the tag there, where I saw a slightly different description:

> Questions about GIMP, the GNU Image Manipulation Program. It is a freely distributed piece of software for such tasks as photo retouching, image composition and image authoring. **Ask scripting questions on Stack Overflow, software support questions on Super User, and anything related to design here on Graphic Design.**

This implies to me that SU is pointing questions about using the program towards GD, while GD points the same kind of questions towards SU. Which one is the correct site to ask this?

Comment: To clarify, you're asking about the usage of the GIMP tag rather than where to ask your linked question?  This seems to be the case here as far as I can tell.

Comment: It seems clear that they want to know where to ask a question about the program, not where to ask a question about usage of a particular tag. The tag text is included because it provides contradictory advice.

Answer (score 9):

I'm a Super User mod and it's in scope for us.

Comment: Thanks, I've submitted an edit suggestion to the tag to clarify the language used.

Comment: [related image?](https://i.redd.it/ud2xieot4l031.jpg)

Comment: I think the question here is more about the tag text (and use guidance) than where to ask the question.  It seems reasonable that the tag text on all three sites should be the same in order to maintain consistency.

Comment: That might be very much more an issue for the individual sites

Comment: @Snow A bit of both, really. The tag text was unclear so I didn't exactly know where to post (I figured the Q would just get migrated if it was wrong) and at the same time I felt like it was a good idea to point attention to the tag.

Comment: @MMM since [this Q&A is extremely similar](https://superuser.com/a/1046625/419485), if not a duplicate, it favors the site the Moderator suggests - usually you can search for similar questions and see which of several sites (if there's that many choices) offers the *best* answers; and ask where there's the faster and more useful answers, over somewhere where such questions generate less interest and have fewer with expertise.